# How to add reviewers, assignees and labels by default when create pull requests in IntelliJ

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

To my team's rules, I have to add some reviewers, assignees, and labels every time I create a pull request. This is boring and wasting time waiting for the user list from Github. Is there a way to do that locally and automatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IDE sends a request to GitHub API to provide you with the most actual and accurate list of users, so there is no option to make this process completely local.